# What is the shutter "rate" of the elecronic shutter on various mirrorless cameras?

Tags: shutter, rolling-shutter

The **shutter rate** ([coined by dpreview editors afaik](https://www.dpreview.com/articles/5816661591/electronic-shutter-rolling-shutter-and-flash-what-you-need-to-know)) is the time it takes for the camera to expose and read the entire sensor in electronic shutter mode, it is different from the "shutter speed" which indicates the duration of exposure of each photosite and can be thought of as the "sync speed" of an electronic shutter as well as the fastest shutter speed at which no "rolling shutter" artifacts are to be expected (though not guaranteeing motion freezing).

Of specific interest are the Fujifilm X-T2, X-T20, X-T3, X-E3, X-H1 and X-100F as well as the recently introduced full-frame mirrorless cameras from Nikon Canon and Sony.

Comment: Since each photosite is never exposed simultaneously with all other photosites with a CMOS sensor, what makes you think a certain "sync speed" will eliminate rolling shutter artifacts? The sensor will always be exposed sequentially. A shorter read out means less 'slope' in the graphs included in the linked article (*reducing* but not *eliminating* the effects of rolling shutter), but there will always be some. Global shutters require CCD sensors. As far as I know, all of the cameras you mention have CMOS sensors.

Comment: This looks like it might be an [X→Y question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/348605). What is the root problem you want to solve? What kind of photos do you wish to take without any demonstrable rolling shutter effect?

Comment: About the global shutter needing ccd part https://m.dpreview.com/news/4957030386/canon-introduces-global-shutter-cmos-sensor-with-improved-dynamic-range

Comment: @lijat "Canon says it will explore use of the chip in measurement and industrial applications, and consider applications in video production." At this point it's still not available in *any* consumer product and Canon does not appear to be interested in placing it anywhere near a 'Stills' camera or any other application where image quality is a significant factor. It's intended application is machine vision.

Comment: Update the penultimate sentence in my original comment above to read: ^^ *If you wish to purchase a camera offered via retail channels for taking still images that has a* Global shutter *you will only find a few marginal (or long out of date) models that use* CCD sensors. ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shutter rates, as measured by Jim Kasson - [blog.kasson.com](http://blog.kasson.com)

```
typical mechanical shutter      1/250

Nikon Z6                         1/37
Nikon Z7                         1/16
Nikon D850 (full)                1/15
Nikon D850 (crop)                1/40
Sony A9                         1/150
Sony A7RIII (normal mode)        1/15
Sony A7RIII (continuous mode)    1/30
Sony A7III (normal mode)         1/16
Sony A7III (continuous mode)     1/28
Sony A7S (full)                  1/30
Sony A7S (crop)                  1/50
Fujifilm GFX-50S                  1/4
```

Comment: I can't seem to find the information in Kasson's blog. You linked to his top level domain. Was that information in a particular article, or was it culled from several individual articles?

Comment: @scottbb the information is scattered across multiple posts, use the search form, e.g. silent shutter

Comment: wow. Well, many kudos for compiling all those numbers. Good job.